# Has this graph-theoretic problem got a known name? Is it NP-hard?

Tags: graphs, trees, np-hard, dag

I am considering the following problem.

We are given a Directed Acyclic Graph. In general, there would be some number of subgraphs that, contracted into one node, would make it a tree. For example, in this graph:

[image: DAG]

If I contract the nodes $b$ and $c$ into a single node, I obtain a tree (quite a trivial one in this case):

[image: Collapsed]

In this example, only one subgraph had to be contracted, but in general more than one subgraph can be required. Note that this is not the only possibility, as contracting $c$ and $d$ would have been also fine. Also, trivially the entire graph could be contracted to obtain a trivial tree of a single node, so we have to look for a minimal solution.

So, the problem I am considering is: Given a DAG, find a set of minimal subgraphs which contractions would turn the DAG into a tree.

Is this problem $NP$-hard? Has it got a specific known name?

Comment: No, collapsing (or contracting) means to substitute the nodes with one node, preserving in this new node all the edges pointing to or starting from the collapsed nodes, removing duplicate edges that might form.

Comment: I thought it were a fairly standard graph-theoretic concept, sorry if it isn't

Comment: Is the set of minimal subgraphs minimal in the sense of number of nodes, or number of subgraphs? For example, in your case I could pick a single subgraph of the entire dag and compress it into one node.

Comment: Minimal, not minimum. I mean subgraphs for which, if you remove one node, they do not fulfill the requirement anymore (of turning the graph into a tree if collapsed). The number of nodes or the number of subgraphs is not important, as long as the chosen set is minimal. In the example above, collapsing the entire graph _does_ fulfill the requirement, but is not a _minimal_ solution, because if I collapse everything excepting node 'a' it still fulfills the requirement.

Comment: Can you specify your problem more formally? You want a partition of the vertices into sets $S_1,\ldots,S_m$ such that after collapsing each $S_i$ into a single vertex $v_i$ what remains is a tree, **and** some other condition, but I don't understand your other condition. Do you want the partition to be such that no refinement is also a solution?

Comment: You may define the problem clearly, if you are looking for a good answer. Contraction is an operation on edges, which means that the edge becomes a vertex. Merging is defined on a set of vertices, which merges a set of vertices/subgraph into a single vertex, keeping all the edges in their place. Would you formally define you "collapse" operation?

Comment: Yes, then I mean "merging". I'll edit the question as soon as possible, thanks

Comment: I believe the established term for your operation is *minorization*. You're looking for a maximal [minor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_minor) that is a tree. Maximum as defined by the *is-minor-of* relation.

Comment: @reinierpost Yes, you got the point

Comment: @gigabytes Finding the biggest tree that is a minor of a graph is a problem that can be solved in polynomial time. You find the biggest spanning tree, this can be done in polynomial time according to this: [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum_spanning_tree#Related_problems). Then you delete all edges that don´t belong to the spanning tree. Now for the version when the only operation you can do is merging vertices, i don´t know

Comment: @rotia Does deleting edges that do not belong to a spanning tree result into a minor?

Comment: @rotia Oh I got it. Well yes it's technically a minor I suppose, but I have to merge nodes not only remove edges

Comment: @gigabytes According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_minor), the three operations that are valid to convert a graph into a minor are: deleting vertices, deleting edges and merging edges. The operation you talk about, i think, is the same than merging edges. The problem is that the trees that you obtain by deleting edges are not the same that the ones you obtain by contracting edges, so that makes the problem tricky

Comment: Have you tried whether a simple greedy algorithm , like: as long as the graph is not a tree "find an edge on a cycle (in the underlying undirected graph) and contract this edge", works?